# Is there any reason for changing the channels order of an image from RGB to BGR?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I've been following [this keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/video_transformers/) video classification tutorial where in the [data preparation](https://keras.io/examples/vision/video_transformers/#data-preparation) section, they load the frames of a video in the `load_video` function pretty generically, but what caught my eye was this line:

```
frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
```

This is the first time I encounter this, most of the times you will just append the frame "as-is" to your list of frames, but here they change the order of the channels (if I'm not mistaken) from RGB to BGR, I couldn't find anything related to it in the web or their docs, can someone give me some insight for this decision?

Comment: If all you do uses channels coherently, there is no problem. Even working with swapped color planes when training for deep-learning is harmless as the system will never know that the colors are not realistic. But then you need to keep the swap !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From experience, the reason why the order can change is dependent on the framework you are using to load in images.  OpenCV in particular orders the channels in BGR format because of [mostly historical reasons that are now outdated](https://learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/).  Because of this, we are unfortunately stuck with this design choice.  Images in the regular RGB format can be seen with scikit-image, matplotlib and Pillow.

In fact, if you look at the `load_video` function, it uses OpenCV to open up a video so the frames coming in are BGR format.  Therefore, the swapping of channels is mandatory to get it to RGB format:

```
def load_video(path, max_frames=0):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    frames = []
    try:
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            frame = crop_center(frame)
            frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
            frames.append(frame)

            if len(frames) == max_frames:
                break
    finally:
        cap.release()
    return np.array(frames)
```

You of course do not need to reverse the channels as a neural network will learn based on the input data that it was provided, but people tend to do this so that it's easy to debug images and not have to worry about continuously reversing the channels for display.  Specifically, if a neural network was trained in BGR ordering, if you loaded in images in RGB format then the reversal of the channels needs to be done as that was how the image channels were represented in training.  All in all, it depends on the framework but you need to keep this in mind when using a neural network after it has been trained.  If the data was trained in BGR format, if your images are read in RGB format you'll need to reverse the channels prior to inference.

In fact, this is a common bug when using networks!  Be extremely diligent and understand how the image data was preprocessed for the network before using it.

Comment: Curious to know what optimizations required BGR rather than RGB?  Why is BGR any better than RGB?

Comment: @fmw42 good question! It was mostly for historical reasons. This was the format most compatible to camera manufacturers so once you loaded in the data, you didn't have to do any additional manipulations to get it to the format we eventually are familiar with: https://learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/

Comment: Btw you just saved me a headache, I was going to use a pre-trained model that was trained on the coco dataset which expects BGR format.

Comment: The “compatible with camera manufacturers” reason is a misunderstanding. If they really used  BGR for that reason, it’s quite sad. BRG makes sense in a little-endian machine, where the RGB triplet written as R<<16 + G<<8 + B stores the values in BGR order in the 24-bit word. But then again, why would you then write the triplet like that? I think the true reason has to do with translation of some old code from a big-endian to little-endian machine. And now OpenCV is stuck with this mistake. :/

Comment: @ImSo3K Nice.  Glad to have helped!

Comment: In the linked blog post, “Windows, when specifying color value using COLORREF they use the BGR format 0x00bbggrr.” — Windows has always been used on a little-median machine, so 0x00bbggrr is stored in memory as “rrggbb00”, or RGB!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Haha I didn't know that.  Thanks for the lesson!